# Problem getting vite to work with vue, laravel and scss

Tags: laravel, vue.js, sass, vuejs2, vite

I'm having a lot of trouble finding any answers to this problem specifically, so here I am. I have an existing Vue2/Laravel project, which previously used webpack/mix. I've decided to replace mix with vite, but I'm having a lot of trouble getting it to work.

First I followed of these instructions: https://owenconti.com/posts/replacing-laravel-mix-with-vite#walkthrough , when it didn't work I mixed it with a few things from another project I work on. At the moment my code looks like this:

**vite.config.js**

```
import {createVuePlugin} from 'vite-plugin-vue2';

import {defineConfig} from 'vite';

const resolve = {
    alias: {
        '@': 'js',
    },
};

export default defineConfig(({command}) => {
    const production = command !== 'serve';

    const plugins = [
        createVuePlugin(),
    ];

    return {
        base: production ? '/js/' : '',
        build: {
            assetsInclude: [],
            manifest: true,
            outDir: 'public/js',
            rollupOptions: {
                input: 'resources/js/app.js',
            },
        },
        plugins,
        server: {
            port: 3000,
        },
        resolve,
        css: {
            preprocessorOptions: {
                scss: {
                    quietDeps: true,
                },
            },
        },

        // Vite bugs if you build out dir is inside the public dir so we change that to something else
        publicDir: 'random_non_existent_folder',
    };
});
```

**postcss.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        require('sass-loader'),
    ],
}
```

**package.json** (shortened, removed a few packages I don't think are relevant)

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "vite": "vite",
        "build": "vite:build",
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.2.31",
        "axios": "^0.21.4",
        "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.4.8",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.4",
        "sass": "^1.49.9",
        "sass-loader": "^12.6.0",
        "ts-loader": "^9.2.7",
        "vite": "^2.8.6",
        "vite-plugin-vue2": "^1.9.3",
        "vue-cli-plugin-i18n": "^2.3.1",
        "vue-loader": "^15.9.8",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap": "^4.6.1",
        "bootstrap-vue": "^2.21.2",
        "bootstrap-vue-editable-table": "^0.1.2-beta.4",
        "prettier": "^2.5.1",
        "vue": "^2.6.14",
        "vue-i18n": "^8.27.0",
        "vue-router": "^3.5.3",
        "vuex": "^3.6.2"
    },
    "resolutions": {
        "ansi-regex": "5.0.1"
    }
}
```

**welcome.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>{{env('APP_NAME')}}</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@200;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=vueRecaptchaApiLoaded&render=explicit" async defer>
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app"></div>
        <script type="module" src="http://localhost:3000/@vite/client"></script>
        <script type="module" src="http://localhost:3000/resources/js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Loading the page just shows a very annoying  `/client">` on the page and nothing else. In the Network tab I can see it tries to download all the files currently in `resources/js/` and succeeds for most of them. In the commandline I ran my `npm run vite` it shows the error "Internal server error: Cannot read property 'getOptions' of undefined'", pointing at the plugin vite:css on 3 accounts of sass-loader in different parts.

In all it looks like I can't get vite to run a local client, if I change some things around I've managed to run an old public app.js build (from months ago), but not reactive or recent. Is there something I'm missing? If someone can point me in the direction I should be looking, I'd greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: I used this to get my project working, [reference](https://sebastiandedeyne.com/vite-with-laravel/)